# Overloading Bitwise And(&) Operator and "*this" in Class Functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

I have several questions about this particular piece of code. I should first mention that `pChar` will always be a dynamic character array that is resized when needed by methods I have not listed.  I have scoured my reference manual and this website but cannot seem to gain a clear understanding of how the & operator works in full.  I also do not want to use an alternative as this is an assignment and am not allowed to.  I've been at this for days so any help would be appreciated.

1. What exactly is `*this` pointing to when using the & operator?
     I have been assuming it points to the left operand.
2. If this is not the case, how do I access the left operand within the & operator method?
3. If this is all completely incorrect, how can I reach the desired outcome by using the overloaded `operator&`?

Method for & operator:

```
PDS_String & PDS_String::operator & (const PDS_String & Str)const
{
     PDS_String temp(*this);
     strcat(temp.pChar, Str.pChar);
     return temp;
}
```

Main:

```
void main ()
{
        PDS_String String1;
        PDS_String String2;
        PDS_String String3;

        String1 = "monkey";
        String2 = "chicken";
        String3 = String1 & String2;  
// Desired outcome for String3 is "monkeychicken"
}
```

Class:

```
class PDS_String
{
public:
    PDS_String();                       //Default
    PDS_String(const PDS_String &);     //Copy
    ~PDS_String();                      //Destructor

    char *          operator &   (const PDS_String &) const;  // Concatenation
    PDS_String &    operator =   (const char *);    // Assignment

// I haven't listed all methods and operator overloads

private:
    char *      pChar;
    long        NumChars;
    long        NumSlots;
};
```

Assignment operator method:

```
    PDS_String & PDS_String::operator = (const char * Str)
    {
        if (pChar == Str)
            return *this;
        else
        {
            if (NumSlots < strlen(Str))
            {
                delete[] pChar;
                pChar = new char[(strlen(Str) + 1)];
                NumSlots = (strlen(Str));
            }
            else;
        }
        strcpy(pChar, Str);
        NumChars = strlen(Str);
         return *this;
    }
```

Thank you very much Matt McNabb.  I have changed the operator& method to reflect your suggestion:

```
char * PDS_String::operator & (const PDS_String & Str)const
{
     char * temp;
     temp = new char[strlen(pChar)+strlen(Str.pChar)+1];
     temp = pChar;
     strcat(pChar, Str.pChar);
     return temp;
}
```

Comment: So you know, there is no reference operator. `&` is used to declare a reference and as the address-of operator and the bitwise AND operator. References aren't pointers, so they don't point to anything, and thus, `*this` doesn't point to anything.

Comment: That's not the reference operator. That's the Bitwise AND operator... The reference operator doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the post.  Any suggestions as far as my questions go?

Comment: [strcat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) requires the destination have enough space after the null terminating char for the src plus a null terminating char. How are your assuring that? I am guessing showing the body of the code that does this operation: `String1 = "monkey";` may be helpful.

Comment: I've added my code for the assignment operator Shafik.

Comment: I would advise learning to write code without writing your own operator overloads before trying to overload operators.  If you cannot reliably get `c = f(a,b)` to work, do not dive into `c = a&b`.  Learn to walk first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `*this` refers to the left-hand operand. `this` points to the left-hand operand.
2. N/A
3. Stop returning a reference to a local object. `temp` ceases to exist when the function ends, so the caller has a dangling reference (causing undefined behaviour).

The normal semantics for a binary operator is to return an object by value. So you could change to `PDS_String PDS_String::operator & (const PDS_String & Str)const` and everything will be fine.

Usually what's done is that the `operator+=` function is a member function that changes `*this`, and then you have a free function `X operator+(X x1, X x2) { return x1 += x2; }`.  You could do the same thing with `operator&` and `operator&=`.

You also have no protection against somebody trying to concatenate a long string and overflowing however much memory is allocated to `pChar`, you will need to add checks for that.

Comment: Thank you @MattMcNabb.  I didn't realize that the destructor was called for the local variable before the returned value could be assigned.  I appreciate the clarification and the very clear and concise way in which you answered all of my questions and specifically the "this" debacle I was experiencing.  You're the best.